# How to get entries from indexedDB by key with some offset?

Tags: pagination, offset, indexeddb

I'm trying to get entries from indexedDB by key and apply some offset.

I have some data at indexedDb like this:

```
[
{id: 0, status: 'valid', message: 'some message ....'},
{id: 1, status: 'invalid', message: 'some message....'},
{id: 2, status: 'warning', message: 'some message....'},
{id: 3, status: 'valid', message: 'some message....'},
{id: 4, status: 'valid', message: 'some message....'},
{id: 5, status: 'valid', message: 'some message....'}
]
```

I have to filter data by 'status' key and render it with pagination, so if I have 20 entries with 'valid' status, I have to render only 15 and set pagination. Everything is ok with first page, but I can't create correct request to indexedDB in order to get entries with key 'valid' but with offset=15. How I can do this? I've tried this, but db.getAllFromIndex doesn't take offset or I don't understand how to pass it. I use 'idb' package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb

```
const db = await openDB('DB', 1, {
         upgrade(db) {
              if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('dbName')) {
                  db.createObjectStore('dbName').createIndex('status', 'status', {unique: false});
               }
               //...code for setting data here...
          };


async getData(filter, offset = 0) {
    const tx = db.transaction('dbName'),
        range = offset ? IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(offset, true) : null,
        items = filter === 'all'
            ? await db.getAll('dbName', range, rules.limit)// everything ok with plain data without filtering by key
            : await db.getAllFromIndex('dbName', 'status', filter, rules.limit),// bug is here! should be offset

        pagination = ...some code for define pagination...

    await tx.done;
    return { items, pagination };
}
```

So how I can do this correctly? Thanks

Comment: you can use IDBCursor.prototype.advance to jump to an offset, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor/advance

Comment: Thank you, it works!